# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module with MySQL installed

Tags: python, django, apple-m1

### Hardware configuration

I'm configuring my new MacBook Air with Apple silicon M1 chip and obviously mac os 11 Big Sur.

### Environment

I have installed

With Homebrew:

- `mysql@5.7`

With `pyenv@1.2.21`:

- `python@3.6.5`

With `pip@20.3.3`:

- `mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1`

### The issue

I work with Django framework and the last step for me is to configure the MySQL database on localhost.
MySQL server is running and I can use it from the shell and access it by SequelPro.
When I run `python manage.py migrate` I have this problem :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

The database configuration is:
[DATABASE environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lqgx.png)

Does someone have the same problem?

Comment: Have you tried ```pip install mysqlclient``` ?

Comment: @BriseBalloches Yes, but still have this issue

Comment: and did you edit __init__.py file as in this post suggests https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46902357/error-loading-mysqldb-module-did-you-install-mysqlclient-or-mysql-python

Comment: @BriseBalloches I can't use pymysql because I'm not the only one who uses this project. I have tried with this package but he gives me another error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`. I search for this error and I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56820895/migrations-error-in-django-2-attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-dec  for me is not the right solution. I don't want to change the code of django/backends it would be unsustainable. I hope you understand my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

try this command :

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Here is documentation : https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

Comment: Hi mysqlclient is installed I have the 1.4.2.post1 version